# Is it possible to sign in and load a user's desktop programmatically from a windows 7 service on the local machine?

Tags: c++, windows, authentication, windows-7, windows-services

**The problem:**
We are using a windows 7 machine to display information on a monitor. This machine is hard to reach and has no keyboard or mouse attached. After a user logs onto this machine using remote desktop, then logs off, it becomes stuck at the "Press CTRL+ALT+DELETE" screen and I have to plug a keyboard and mouse into it to sign back in to the user account which is responsible for displaying the correct information on the monitor.

I am developing a windows service in C++ that looks at the current sessions to see when a user logs in and out of remote desktop. I want to have this service sign back into the correct user and display the user's desktop after the user logs out.

Right now I am stuck trying to find a way to have a service sign into a user account and display their desktop on the monitor. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/152435/remote-desktop-with-other-user-still-logged-on

Comment: You can configure the machine to log on automatically with a given username and password.  The ForceAutoLogon setting makes the automatic logon kick in as soon as a user logs off rather than only when the machine is rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can impersonate a user, load a user's registry hive, and launch processes with that user's account, but in Vista and later disallow interactive services, so you can't do anything that interacts with a user desktop.  What you can do is IPC (inter-process communication) between the service process and a running user process, via TCP, named pipes, and other means, but only if the user is already logged in with a desktop.  You can't start a user desktop session.

More info:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22windows+7%22+interactive+service

As for how to get around not having a keyboard to issue Ctrl-Alt-Delete (even though that's not really the question you asked), you may be able to use the on-screen keyboard, depending on UAC settings.

By the way, this isn't a C++-specific question at all; you can use the entire Windows API with regular old C.